# Ruby FFI gem cannot open library file

Tags: ruby, ffi

I have two files in the same path, functions.dll and functions.rb which has this content:

```
require 'ffi'

module Foos
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib 'functions'
end
```

When I run this it throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

        4: from functions.rb:6:in <main>
        3: from functions.rb:9:in <module:Foos>
        2: from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ffi-1.11.1-x64-mingw32/lib/ffi/library.rb:98:in ffi_lib
        1: from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ffi-1.11.1-x64-mingw32/lib/ffi/library.rb:98:in map

C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ffi-1.11.1-x64-mingw32/lib/ffi/library.rb:151:in block in ffi_lib: Could not open  (LoadError): The specified module could not be found.
Could not open library 'functions.dll': The specified module could not be found.
```

Any idea why it might not be finding the file?

Answer (score 2):

Provide it full path.

```
ffi_lib File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/functions.dll'
```

or

```
ffi_lib File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/functions'
```